# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD}"

Tags: jsf, maven, websphere, icefaces, myfaces

I am unable to  deploy the web application on the websphere.
I am getting the following error. Other developers in my team dont seem to face this.
Your inputs will help.

Thank you in advance,
lucky

```
[11/18/13 13:35:11:655 CST] 00000044 annotation    W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper collectClasses SRVE8000W: Skipped class that failed to initialize for annotation scanning.
                                 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: .{com.xyzFirm.web.filter.LoginFilter.class}
    at java.lang.Class.forNameImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:219)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper.loadClass(WASAnnotationHelper.java:753)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper.collectClasses(WASAnnotationHelper.java:188)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper.<init>(WASAnnotationHelper.java:143)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelperManager.getAnnotationHelper(WASAnnotationHelperManager.java:63)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.metadata.WebMetaDataFactory.handOffReferenceData(WebMetaDataFactory.java:440)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.metadata.WebMetaDataFactory.createMetaData(WebMetaDataFactory.java:413)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.MetaDataMgrImpl.createMetaDataFromFactories(MetaDataMgrImpl.java:228)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.MetaDataMgrImpl.createMetaData(MetaDataMgrImpl.java:411)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:630)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:968)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:769)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2172)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:445)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:388)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:116)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$CUInitializer.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:994)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:349)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1783)

[11/18/13 13:35:12:066 CST] 00000044 webapp        I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl WebGroup SRVE0169I: Loading Web Module: OrderEntryWeb.
[11/18/13 13:35:12:256 CST] 00000044 WASSessionCor I SessionContextRegistry getSessionContext SESN0176I: Will create a new session context for application key default_host/oe
[11/18/13 13:35:13:338 CST] 00000044 SystemErr     R SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
[11/18/13 13:35:13:338 CST] 00000044 SystemErr     R SLF4J: Found binding in [wsjar:file:/C:/Users/c201002/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.0.9/logback-classic-1.0.9.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
[11/18/13 13:35:13:338 CST] 00000044 SystemErr     R SLF4J: Found binding in [bundleresource://241.fwk1003291197:1/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
[11/18/13 13:35:13:338 CST] 00000044 SystemErr     R SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
[11/18/13 13:35:13:487 CST] 00000044 SystemErr     R SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
[11/18/13 13:35:14:836 CST] 00000044 webapp        I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp log SRVE0292I: Servlet Message - [OrderEntryEAR#OrderEntryWeb-1.0.22-SNAPSHOT.war]:.No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
[11/18/13 13:35:14:859 CST] 00000044 webapp        I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp log SRVE0292I: Servlet Message - [OrderEntryEAR#OrderEntryWeb-1.0.22-SNAPSHOT.war]:.Set web app root system property: 'OrderEntryWeb' = [C:\workspaces\oe_1114\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\OrderEntryWeb]
[11/18/13 13:35:14:861 CST] 00000044 webapp        I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp log SRVE0292I: Servlet Message - [OrderEntryEAR#OrderEntryWeb-1.0.22-SNAPSHOT.war]:.Initializing Logback from [file:///${AXE_APPCONFIG}/logback-oe.groovy]
[11/18/13 13:35:15:031 CST] 00000044 FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv03\logs\ffdc\server1_177b803c_13.11.18_13.35.14.871637535233665644227.txt com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated 1341
[11/18/13 13:35:15:032 CST] 00000044 webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp notifyServletContextCreated SRVE0283E: Exception caught while initializing context: {0}
                                 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'AXE_APPCONFIG' in string value "file:///${AXE_APPCONFIG}/logback-oe.groovy"
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:173)
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:125)
    at org.springframework.util.SystemPropertyUtils.resolvePlaceholders(SystemPropertyUtils.java:80)
    at org.springframework.util.SystemPropertyUtils.resolvePlaceholders(SystemPropertyUtils.java:64)
    at ch.qos.logback.ext.spring.LogbackConfigurer.initLogging(LogbackConfigurer.java:70)
    at ch.qos.logback.ext.spring.web.WebLogbackConfigurer.initLogging(WebLogbackConfigurer.java:142)
    at ch.qos.logback.ext.spring.web.LogbackConfigListener.contextInitialized(LogbackConfigListener.java:54)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:1651)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:414)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:169)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:749)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:634)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:426)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:718)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1170)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1370)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:638)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:968)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:769)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2172)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:445)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:388)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:116)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$CUInitializer.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:994)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:349)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1783)

[11/18/13 13:35:15:080 CST] 00000044 FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv03\logs\ffdc\server1_177b803c_13.11.18_13.35.15.0778685862705566100309.txt com.ibm.ws.naming.util.Helpers.processSerializedObjectForLookupExt 1089
[11/18/13 13:35:15:086 CST] 00000044 FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv03\logs\ffdc\server1_177b803c_13.11.18_13.35.15.0834183658295955420827.txt com.ibm.ws.naming.util.Helpers.processSerializedObjectForLookupExt 1100
[11/18/13 13:35:15:092 CST] 00000044 FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv03\logs\ffdc\server1_177b803c_13.11.18_13.35.15.0886126654825728730179.txt com.ibm.ws.naming.util.Helpers.logJndiContextException 1504
[11/18/13 13:35:15:141 CST] 00000044 config        I   Initializing Mojarra 2.1.26 ( 20130905-1451 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.1.26@12478) for context '/oe'
[11/18/13 13:35:15:988 CST] 00000044 application   I   JSF1048: PostConstruct/PreDestroy annotations present.  ManagedBeans methods marked with these annotations will have said annotations processed.
[11/18/13 13:35:16:855 CST] 00000044 application   I   Unable to discern ProjectStage for value ${javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE}.
[11/18/13 13:35:16:931 CST] 00000044 config        E   Critical error during deployment: 
                                 com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: 
  Source Document: wsjar:file:/C:/Users/c201002/.m2/repository/org/icefaces/icefaces-ee/3.3.0-P01/icefaces-ee-3.3.0-P01.jar!/META-INF/faces-config.xml
  Cause: Unable to create a new instance of 'org.icefaces.impl.application.WindowScopeManager$DetermineOrDisposeScope': java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD}"
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.createInstance(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:293)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.LifecycleConfigProcessor.addPhaseListeners(LifecycleConfigProcessor.java:132)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.LifecycleConfigProcessor.process(LifecycleConfigProcessor.java:111)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:114)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.process(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:222)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:361)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:216)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:1651)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:414)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:169)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:749)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:634)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:426)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:718)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1170)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1370)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:638)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:968)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:769)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2172)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:445)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:388)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:116)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$CUInitializer.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:994)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:349)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1783)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD}"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:430)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:483)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationAssociate.createFaceletFactory(ApplicationAssociate.java:652)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationAssociate.<init>(ApplicationAssociate.java:231)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.<init>(ApplicationImpl.java:214)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationFactoryImpl.getApplication(ApplicationFactoryImpl.java:107)
    at com.sun.faces.config.InitFacesContext.getApplication(InitFacesContext.java:143)
    at org.icefaces.impl.application.WindowScopeManager$DetermineOrDisposeScope.<init>(WindowScopeManager.java:524)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1616)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.createInstance(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:268)
    ... 27 more

[11/18/13 13:35:17:093 CST] 00000044 FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv03\logs\ffdc\server1_177b803c_13.11.18_13.35.16.9361464423135162535211.txt com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated 1341
[11/18/13 13:35:17:094 CST] 00000044 webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp notifyServletContextCreated SRVE0283E: Exception caught while initializing context: {0}
                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: 
  Source Document: wsjar:file:/C:/Users/c201002/.m2/repository/org/icefaces/icefaces-ee/3.3.0-P01/icefaces-ee-3.3.0-P01.jar!/META-INF/faces-config.xml
  Cause: Unable to create a new instance of 'org.icefaces.impl.application.WindowScopeManager$DetermineOrDisposeScope': java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD}"
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:276)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:1651)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:414)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:169)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:749)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:634)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:426)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:718)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1170)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1370)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:638)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:968)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:769)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2172)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:445)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:388)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:116)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$CUInitializer.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:994)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:349)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1783)
Caused by: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: 
  Source Document: wsjar:file:/C:/Users/c201002/.m2/repository/org/icefaces/icefaces-ee/3.3.0-P01/icefaces-ee-3.3.0-P01.jar!/META-INF/faces-config.xml
  Cause: Unable to create a new instance of 'org.icefaces.impl.application.WindowScopeManager$DetermineOrDisposeScope': java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD}"
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.createInstance(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:293)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.LifecycleConfigProcessor.addPhaseListeners(LifecycleConfigProcessor.java:132)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.LifecycleConfigProcessor.process(LifecycleConfigProcessor.java:111)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:114)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.process(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:222)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:361)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:216)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD}"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:430)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:483)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationAssociate.createFaceletFactory(ApplicationAssociate.java:652)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationAssociate.<init>(ApplicationAssociate.java:231)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.<init>(ApplicationImpl.java:214)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationFactoryImpl.getApplication(ApplicationFactoryImpl.java:107)
    at com.sun.faces.config.InitFacesContext.getApplication(InitFacesContext.java:143)
    at org.icefaces.impl.application.WindowScopeManager$DetermineOrDisposeScope.<init>(WindowScopeManager.java:524)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1616)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.createInstance(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:268)
    ... 27 more

[11/18/13 13:35:17:097 CST] 00000044 webapp        I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp log SRVE0292I: Servlet Message - [OrderEntryEAR#OrderEntryWeb-1.0.22-SNAPSHOT.war]:.Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
[11/18/13 13:35:17:109 CST] 00000044 SystemOut     O 13:35:17.103 [server.startup : 2] INFO  o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
[11/18/13 13:35:17:145 CST] 00000044 SystemOut     O 13:35:17.145 [server.startup : 2] DEBUG o.s.c.i.s.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver - Found Equinox FileLocator for OSGi bundle URL resolution
[11/18/13 13:35:17:227 CST] 00000044 SystemOut     O 13:35:17.227 [server.startup : 2] DEBUG o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment - Initializing new StandardServletEnvironment
[11/18/13 13:35:17:228 CST] 00000044 SystemOut     O 13:35:17.228 [server.startup : 2] DEBUG o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment - Adding [servletConfigInitParams] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
[11/18/13 13:35:17:228 CST] 00000044 SystemOut     O 13:35:17.228 [server.startup : 2] DEBUG o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment - Adding [servletContextInitParams] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
[11/18/13 13:35:17:232 CST] 00000044 SystemOut     O 13:35:17.232 [server.startup : 2] DEBUG o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment - Adding [jndiProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
[11/18/13 13:35:17:233 CST] 00000044 SystemOut     O 13:35:17.233 [server.startup : 2] DEBUG o.s.w.c.s.StandardSer
```

Comment: What is the context of this?  Post code and context of your error.  We can't read your mind.

Comment: All I am trying to do is run the SVN checked out project on my local machine and I get the above error. I didnt even make any code changes yet.

Answer (score 0):

`Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD}"` looks like there is something wrong with your maven resource filtering.

Maybe everyone else on your team has different maven settings? Are you using the correct profile?

Comment: Hello Reto, Thank you for the reply. I did set up the profile using the tutorial provided on company wiki link. Is there anything that you want me to specifically look into ?